# mysql запрос с IN возвращает результаты только для первого значения

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!
есть вот код:

```
    if (count($roomsamount) == 1 && in_array(4, $roomsamount)) {
        array_push($roomsamount, '5','6', '7' , '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20');
        $rooms = implode(',', $roomsamount);
    }elseif (count($roomsamount) > 1 && in_array(4, $roomsamount)) {
        array_push($roomsamount, '5','6', '7' , '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20');
        $rooms = implode(',', $roomsamount);
    } elseif (count($roomsamount) > 1 && !in_array(4, $roomsamount)) {
        $rooms = implode(', ', $roomsamount);
    } else {
        $rooms = implode(', ', $roomsamount);
    }
}
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM flats WHERE roomAmount IN ('$rooms') ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $page, $per_page");
```

Передается в IN, например (3,4,5), но, запрос возвращает результаты только для первого параметра, будто для In задано только (3) игнорируя все остальные. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: например не заключать в кавычки переменную `'$rooms'`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поведения что их наличие что отсутствие никак не меняет и по прежнему работает не так как ожидается :(

Comment: как в итоге выглядит содержимое данной переменной? сделай `echo`и покажи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
SELECT * FROM flats WHERE roomAmount IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 5

Comment: var_dump:
string(16) "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

Comment: а, понял, сейчас вручную прописал и получил и нормальный результат и воспроизведение ошибки.
так понимаю, лучше всего мне в бд сменить для колонки тип с int на varchar? или можно как-то не так извращенно это делать?

Comment: у тебя не может быть запроса `IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` как минимум потому, что у тебя есть одинарные кавычки...так что ты обманываешь где-то

Comment: `мне в бд сменить для колонки тип с int на varchar?` - как раз таки наоборот, раз у тебя колонка  типа `int`, то зачем ты пытаешься пихать строки?.... делай `array_push` и   `implode` просто из чисел.. а дальше вставляй в запрос без обрамления переменной в одинарные кавычки...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я их на всякий случай убрал.

Comment: сделай `echo "SELECT * FROM flats WHERE roomAmount IN ('$rooms') ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $page, $per_page"` без всяких случаев и всё понятно будет. в целом я написал выше что надо бы сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский SELECT * FROM flats WHERE roomAmount IN ('2, 3') ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: видишь, а должно быть `IN (2, 3)` без одинарных

Comment: да, спасибо, с этим разобрались, теперь осталось понять как получаемый с формы массив из строк в числа преобразовать)

Comment: ой, господи-господи, что я за оболтус. наконец-то нашел где мой прокол был главный. там где ниже пагинация я использую почти такое же обращение с ('$rooms'), и смотря на результат я смотрел на количество сгенерированных страниц, вот это называется мучаюсь-мучаюсь а проблема была даже не там где искал, в общем-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо тебе огромное!

Comment: Зачем делать `implode` в каждом `if-else`?

Answer (score 0):

А кавычки IN ('$rooms') походу лишние попробуй без них ($rooms)